# Prevent script requested by CURL (via CRON) from running in browser

Tags: php, security, curl, cron

I have a script which is called via a CURL request in a CRON task once a day. I would like to protect it from being executed on my live domain through a direct browser get request.

At this time I cannot move the CRON to reside above the web root. My current CRON task looks like:

```
curl -q https://example.com/cron/daily/ > /dev/null
```

And then in the head of my CRON controller I was going to use something like:

```
if ((in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], $this->config->item('live_domains'))) AND (IS_CURL)) {
    show_error("Daily CRON tasks can only be run from the command line on the live server.");
}
```

Comment: Use a secret token as a parameter, or lock it down via htaccess in some manner (not 100% effective, but multiple layers ought to help). Even better, move it out of the website and run it from the CLI

Comment: Thanks, I've added a token/key to the app config and I'm now checking for that on the live server before the CRON tasks execute. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cron script runs from the same server things are hosted on, you should be able to add:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '127.0.0.1') {
    show_error("Daily CRON tasks can only be run from the command line on the live server.");
}
```

Or swap 127.0.0.1 with the allowed IP addresses it can run from.

Other than that there is no bullet-proof way to distinguish the job is being run from cURL and is not being spoofed.

Or as CollinD suggested, using a secret token as a parameter and check that.

A better bet might be to use .htaccess:

```
<Location /cron>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

Using this method, you don't need to modify the PHP code, just use Apache to allow/deny access to the cron scripts based on IP.

Comment: Thanks - very helpful suggestions. :)